# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, andengine

My code gives my followings errors:
Unfortunatelly I don't know why... I think it's connected with intent but what is wrong?
Could anybody help me?
Thanks for yours answers!
Main class: [Pastebin1](http://pastebin.com/0nni2UTQ)
Second class: [Pastebin2](http://pastebin.com/RncKmCS5)

> 12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pandus/com.example.pandus.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at com.example.pandus.ParallaxLayer.(ParallaxLayer.java:57)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at com.example.pandus.Game.(Game.java:31)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
>   12-15 12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    ... 11 more
>   12-15 12:28:00.579: I/Process(15202): Sending signal. PID: 15202 SIG: 9

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game.java, line 31, the

```
private SmoothCamera camera;
new ParallaxLayer(camera, true, 4000);
```

camera is null at that time point.

Comment: Ohhh .. thank you ... It was so stupid mistake ... 
I have one more question .. because i have a little trobule to read this ... Which line gives information that is 31 line of Game.java? I don't want to ask more question like this...

Comment: this line: `12:27:58.887: E/AndroidRuntime(15202): at com.example.pandus.Game.(Game.java:31) 12-15 ` Game.java:31 is the keyword. Which class, what line.

Answer (score 0):

In `Game` class your `SmoothCamera` object needs to be instantiate before you pass it as an argument to `ParallaxLayer` constructor.

I belive you can instantinate both `SmoothCamrea` and `ParallaxLayer` in `onCreateEngineOptions` method